# navigate between two application with routes in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have Two applications that are the same.the diffrence between is one of them is in English language and the other is in persian language.

now I want To have change language button(Persian)  in English version App that when users clicked on it Persian versions Shows Up.

I have English Version as mother source and add components and css of persian app in to my english version app.

routes in react does work fine but I have a problem that the styles for persian version is not Influenced.

I have this routes:

```
class AppEn extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <RootEn />
        <li>
            <Link to='fa'>
                <div className="icLog"></div> <span>fa</span>
            </Link>
        </li>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class AppFa extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <RootFa />
    )
  }
}

class RootTotal extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={AppEn}></Route> 
        <Route path='/fa' component={AppFa}></Route> 
      </Router>
    )
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(
  <RootTotal phrase="ES6" />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and in AppEn i import English styles and in AppFa i import Persian Styles. but only the styles of english is working.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to have language mutations, i recommend u to use something like this - http://www.bebetterdeveloper.com/coding/getting-started-react-flux.html instead of have differents components for each language..